# Create a re-usable question template in Django

Tags: python, django

In Django, I want to create a model for a Questionnaire that can be created and used as a template by the user.

To do this, my thought is to create a Question class with the desired attributes, then create a QuestionTemplate class that will group the questions together into one, re-usable template. However, I'm not sure how to create a class with an unknown number of attributes.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    group = None
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    response = models.TextField()
    rating = Rating(min_value=0, max_value=5)


class QuestionTemplate(models.Model):
    pass
```

I'd like to have the ability to group these user created questions into a template that the user can apply.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Django ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)

An example in your case:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Question

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'
```

On your `views.py`:

```
def someView(req):
    context = {
      'form':form
    }
    return render(req, 'someTemplate.html', context)
```

Now you can access the form on your template like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/someRoute">
{{ form }}
</form>
```